# Resuability of TVS Diodes which are injected by some surge

Tags: usb, tvs

I'm using some TVS diodes for USB protection.
Even if their shields are connected to directly for source GND, I soldered some diodes for electrostatic issues.

I searched this site and Korean wikis, etc... and I heard that "TVS is just for single use". Is it true? In other words, if the electrostatic
(or some surge) is injected at the data pin and then TVS diode will play its own role. Then must I remove the used TVS and solder another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"This can repeat itself for random recurring transient events *indefinitely* within the
rating of the TVS, but only if there is sufficient time for the device to cool before the next event occurs."

https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/129581-micronote-135-failure-mechanisms-for-transient-voltage-suppressors